# Computing magnetic fields contours

Tags: magnetic-fields

I have a set of Velcro-backed magnets of varying strengths that I can stick to a sheet of non-magnetic material. What are the standard techniques for computing the magnetic field lines for an arbitrary placement of these magnets on the sheet? Is there public domain software for solving this problem?

What if one or more of the magnets are quadrupoles? or octopoles?

Comment: For something this general you should use a finite element package. You should be able to find a number if you search for "open source magnetic FEM software" or so. Don't expect high quality easy to use tools for free, though and even the expensive tools are hard to use. If all you want is to know how well these things stick... don't waste your time on software, just get the magnets, a fridge and a force gauge. Infinitely faster, infinitely more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a fairly large sheet, and that you are interested in an approximate method, you could use a small compass and mark the *direction* of the magnetic field at many places on a grid. From these directions you can draw field lines; and contours are perpendicular to the field lines.

If that is not good enough for you, it's quite easy to write down the expression for a dipole field; you can compute the field (x and y component) for each magnet and add them together, then take the magnitude and create a contour map with a handful of lines of Matlab / Python code.

Taking account the finite size of bar magnets makes this even harder - if that is the level of accuracy you need I recommend using a real physics simulator - Comsol or other package. Expect to pay for quality...

Comment: Yes, this was the direction I was going in - compute the fields of each magnet independently on a regular grid and sum the values at each point. Then use a contouring algorithm to compute the field lines.

Can you point me to methods/software to compute the individual fields?